# AND search on MySQL many to many table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, many-to-many

I have the below tables I want to do a search on:

```
Table A
+----+----------------------------+
| ID | description                |
+----+----------------------------+
|  0 | horse going bad            |
|  1 | Older Years of Resolutions |
|  2 | The knockknock pirate      |
|  3 | The Wish list              |
|  4 | list that's no list        |
+----+----------------------------+

table TAGS
+----+------------+
| ID | tag        |
+----+------------+
|  0 | list       |
|  1 | knockknock |
+----+------------+

table TAGLINKS
+-------+--------+
| TAGID | JOKEID |
+-------+--------+
|   0   |    2   |
|   0   |    3   |
+-------+--------+
```

When I do this search:

```
select A.* from tags
   join taglinks on tagid=tags.id
   join A on A.id=jokeid
where tag in ('list','knockknock')
```

Gives me all entries in A that have EITHER 'list' or 'knockknock' in their tags (or both) (2,3). What I'm looking for is the query to get entries from table A that are connected to BOTH list and knockknock tagges (2 only).

I'm also Unioning this data with a direct search in the descriptions from table A, which is something to take in consideration..

right now I have:

```
select A.* from tags
   join taglinks on tagid=tags.id
   join A on A.id=jokeid
where tag in ('list','knockknock') 

UNION

select * from A where locate('list',description) and locate('knockknock',description)
```

but I also get 3 from table A, I want only 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that all have the two tags `'list', 'knockknock'` you should add `GROUP BY` clause with `HAVING`:

```
...
WHERE tag in ('list', 'knockknock')
GROUP BY tag
HAVING COUNT(tag) = 2)
```

Something like:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM tags
INNER JOIN taglinks ON tagid = tags.id
INNER JOIN A on A.id=jokeid
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
             FROM tags
             WHERE tag in ('list', 'knockknock')
             GROUP BY tag
             HAVING COUNT(tag) = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of looking at the tags as a set and looking for properties of that set.  I like to approach this using SQL's aggregation functions, in particular, the `having` clause.

```
select A.*
from tags join
     taglinks
     on tagid=tags.id join
     A on A.id=jokeid
group by A.id
having max(tag = 'list') = 1 and
       max(tag = 'knockknock') = 1
```

(Note:  this uses two MySQL-specific syntax conventions.  The `group by` is only on the id column; the rest are "hidden columns".  And, the expression `tag = 'list'` is treated as a real value, so the full `case` statement is not needed.)

By the way, switching this to one tag or another is easy:

```
select A.*
from tags join
     taglinks
     on tagid=tags.id join
     A on A.id=jokeid
group by A.id
having max(tag = 'list') = 1 or
       max(tag = 'knockknock') = 1
```